# Exception error says no data is present. Possible error in coding

Tags: sql-server, datareader

I got two databases.
I'm trying to get the latest ID in test2 and forward that ID to test

```
    SqlCommand readcmd = new SqlCommand("select MAX(PID) from test2;");
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();
    int pid = (int)rdr["PID"];
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (PID) values ('"+ rdr.GetInt32(0) +"')";
```

there should be data because i've checked my table data and there's a lot of records that I intentionally filled. What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlDataReader is a forward only reader.The typical method of reading from the data stream returned by the SqlDataReader is to iterate through each row with a while loop.

```
SqlCommand readcmd = new SqlCommand("select MAX(PID) from test2;");
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int pid = 0;
if(rdr.HasRows)
{  
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           pid = rdr.GetInt32(0);
        }
}
cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (PID) values (@pid)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);
```

Also, in general, you should not directly concatenate the variables into your command text. Use parameters instead to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask what is demoXml?

Comment: See the updated answer. If this solves your problem, please accept this post as an answer.